# How to assign the values to struct while go routines are running?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm using goroutines in my project and I want to to assign the values to the struct fields but I don't know that how I will assign the values get by using mongodb quires to the struct fields I'm showing my struct and the query too.

```
type AppLoadNew struct{
    StripeTestKey      string                   `json:"stripe_test_key" bson:"stripe_test_key,omitempty"`
    Locations          []Locations              `json:"location" bson:"location,omitempty"`
}

type Locations struct{
   Id int `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
   Location  string `json:"location" bson:"location"`
}

func GoRoutine(){
   values := AppLoadNew{}
   go func() {
      data, err := GetStripeTestKey(bson.M{"is_default": true})
      if err == nil {
        values.StripeTestKey := data.TestStripePublishKey
      }
  }()
  go func() {
      location, err := GetFormLocation(bson.M{"is_default": true})
      if err == nil {
        values.Locations := location
      }
  }()
  fmt.Println(values) // Here it will nothing
  // empty
}
```

Can you please help me that I will assign all the values to the `AppLoadNew` struct.

Comment: You're ignoring errors. Those values will be empty if there was an error in your queries, but you're not examining the returned error values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Go no value is safe for concurrent read and write (from multiple goroutines). You must synchronize access.

Reading and writing variables from multiple goroutines can be protected using [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) or [`sync.RWMutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex), but in your case there is something else involved: you should wait for the 2 launched goroutines to complete. For that, the go-to solution is [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

And since the 2 goroutines write 2 different fields of a struct (which act as 2 distinct variables), they don't have to be synchronized to each other (see more on this here: [Can I concurrently write different slice elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879322/can-i-concurrently-write-different-slice-elements/49879469#49879469)). Which means using a `sync.WaitGroup` is sufficient.

This is how you can make it safe and correct:

```
func GoRoutine() {
    values := AppLoadNew{}

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        data, err := GetStripeTestKey(bson.M{"is_default": true})
        if err == nil {
            values.StripeTestKey = data.StripeTestKey
        }
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        location, err := GetFormLocation(bson.M{"is_default": true})
        if err == nil {
            values.Locations = location
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(values)
}
```

See a (slightly modified) working example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/v39lGzTqgpU).

See related / similar questions:

[Reading values from a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444734/reading-values-from-a-different-thread/49445102#49445102)

[golang struct concurrent read and write without Lock is also running ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301328/golang-struct-concurrent-read-and-write-without-lock-is-also-running-ok/51301572#51301572)

[How to make a variable thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863273/how-to-make-a-variable-thread-safe/52882045#52882045)

Comment: can you tell me please that what is the purpose of `wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}` 
 also `wg.Add(1)`.

Comment: Now I'm using 1 go routine for all quires but in go routine I pass all the values into the different function which return the variable assigned all the values to the struct and How i will access that variable?

Comment: @puneet55667788 `wg := ...` creates a new variable called `wg` which will be a `WaitGroup`. `wg.Add(1)` adds one to the wait group's counter, which tells how many times `wg.Done()` have to be called in order to a call to `wg.Wait()` be unblocked. This is used here to make the main goroutine wait all spawned goroutines before it proceeds printing the value of `values`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sync` package with `WaitGroup`, here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Foo struct {
    One string
    Two string
}

func main() {
    f := Foo{}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        // Perform long calculations
        <-time.After(time.Second * 1)
        f.One = "foo"
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        // Perform long calculations
        <-time.After(time.Second * 2)
        f.Two = "bar"

    }()

    fmt.Printf("Before %+v\n", f)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("After %+v\n", f)
}
```

The output:

```
Before {One: Two:}
After {One:foo Two:bar}
```

Comment: a bug found in the code, `wg.Add(1)` should be outside of goroutine

Comment: @WeizhongTu why you think so?

Comment: It is possible that `wg.Wait()` be executed before `wg.Add(1)`.  `wg.Add(1)` may not have been executed yet if in goroutine.

Comment: @WeizhongTu nice catch!